# Transform or replace the jquery.ajax promise

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am hoping to transform the data returned by an ajax call and pass this to another plugin's constructor. I thought that if the plugin's options accepted an object for its data or a function  that returned the data this would allow me to use a deferred object being jQuery.ajax.

The rub is that I need to transform the data on the client side and cannot see how to do this with jQuery.Deferred Object. There are many examples of varying complexity around but not many that deal with passing and transforming arguments.

This is some code that represents what I am trying to achieve.

```
function shapeResults( rawData ) {
    return $.Deferred(function ( dfd ) {

        //transform in someway
        var shapedData = rawData.toUpperCase();

        alert( shapedData );

        //change the 'signature' from jqXHR to data
        dfd.resolve( shapedData );
    }
    ).promise();
}

function useTransformedData ( data ) {
    //hoping for UPPERCASE data here but still getting rawData
    alert( data );
}

$.get( '/' )
.success( shapeResults )
.then( useTransformedData );
```

As it stands the useTransformedData callback always seems to receive the rawData rather than the transformedData.
Is what I am trying possible and if so could someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`success` returns the original `Deferred` object, not the new one.  If you want to transform the data, you need [`deferred.pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)

```
function shapeResults( rawData ) {
    return rawData.toUpperCase();
}

function useTransformedData(data) {
    alert(data);
}

$.get( '/' )
    .pipe( shapeResults )
    .then( useTransformedData );
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxHa2/). There's a couple of changes to make it work on jsFiddle, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Genius, Thanks. It is worth noting that pipe was added in 1.6 which is why I didn't find it reading the source code for 1.5 :)

Comment: Should be noted that `deferred.pipe()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 in favor of an improved `deferred.then()`: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/